# Calling a web service from a script or batch file

Tags: .net, web-services, batch-file

We have a financial product that has built in scheduling capabilities to run over night batches. This product can also use web services to kick off each batch as required.

I want to know if it is possible to call the web services from a .bat file or another type of batch/script file. If this is possible then we can call the batch file from the companies scheduling service (Autosys).

I don't want to write a exe to call this if possible (circumstances outside my control).

KISS approach :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a take on John'o's answer that uses Microsoft.XmlHttp (which should already exist on the server\workstation)

Create a .vbs a

```
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
http.open "GET", "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL", FALSE
http.send ""
WScript.Echo http.responseText
```

Comment: How to handle https URLs?

Answer (score 3):

Hi All I found the answer if anyone else is looking to do the same thing. The following link has an example using a .vb script to call the WS.

http://blogs.msdn.com/bgroth/archive/2004/10/21/246155.aspx

Comment: It's also possible to build the SOAP message by hand and parse  the result, http://www.rgagnon.com/wshdetails/wsh-0033.html

Answer (score 0):

KISS Approach

in your bat file

```
iexplore.exe <url to webpage that consumes the webservice>
```

would that work ?

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes that may work. However wouldn't IE be left open after the call. Not the best solution as this is on a server that may not have anyone logging in for a week of two? Probably not as slick as I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, KISS demands that you not use a scripting language that has no built-in web service support. Anything you do in that language will complicate things just to provide the missing capability.

KISS says create a console application in Visual Studio, add a Service Reference, call the necessary method, then run the console application in your .bat file. .bat files have built-in support for running console applications.

Comment: Yes, but I thought you supplied "KISS" as the reason. I responded that this would not be the simplest way to call a web service in a scripted manner. Calling the service from a console application, which is, in turn, called by the script, would be the simplest.